# Price layered navigation in Magento2 when change the price on the fly

Tags: magento2, event-observer, extensions, layered-navigation

I am building an extension to change the product price on the fly using some observers, everything is okay and works fine except the price layer navigation on the left side.

In the category page view i am using this observer `catalog_product_collection_load_after`. But the Price Layer navigation is not working on the new prices. Anyone have a suggestion.

Note: the price is on customer level

Comment: Any solution for that ?

Comment: @DhairyaShah, nothing till now, i think it is impossible as the data are coming directly from some tables

Answer (score 1):

Event `catalog_product_collection_load_after` is no longer appropriate for this case. In magento 1.9.x there is event `catalog_product_collection_load_before`.

When using event `catalog_product_collection_load_after`, you are changing prices after the collection has been instantiated and made available to the Layer class.

However, in Magento 2 the event `catalog_product_collection_load_before` was not implemented as can be verified in the link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7737.

I believe the solution is rewrite the native Magento collection resource and implement the dispatch for event `catalog_product_collection_load_before`.

Comment: I tried this before but unfortunately it did not work, it looks the price is coming from another place and not coming from the collection it self